# Combine x rows to one row CSV, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe looking like that:

```
  ID  val1 val2 ... val10
1 1   45   2
2 1   34   90 
3 1   90   9
4 1   10   10
...
5000
```

I would like to merge the val-columns combining 10 rows (1-10, 11-20 ...) to 1 row so that it looks like this (every 10 rows the ID Changes, I do not wanna sort the data, just combine 10 rows to 1 row):

```
  ID  val1 val2 ... val100
1 1   45   2
2 2   10   60 
3 3   40   9
4 4   1   140
...
500
```

I am pretty new to pandas and I was only able to find an easy method to sort and then combine rows by having the same column value. The problem is, that I only want to combine the val-columns of 10 rows and sometimes in my date the same ID occurs again.

Comment: You don't need pandas for this.  Just read the file line by line and write the combined lines yourself.

Comment: `df.iloc[0::10, :]` will select every 10th row. From the example in the OP, it's not clear that rows are being combine. To combine the values `df.groupby('ID').sum()`

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create your input dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": range(1, 5001)})
for n in range(1, 11):
    df[f"val{n}"] = np.random.randint(low=0, high=140, size=(5000, 1))

# initialize the output dataframe with the correct size and column names
out_df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((500, 100)))
out_df.columns = [f"val{n}" for n in range(1, 101)]
out_df.index += 1
out_df.index.name = "ID"

# copy the values from df to out_df
for n in range(10):
    out_df.iloc[0:500, n * 10: (n + 1) * 10 ] = df.copy().iloc[500 * n: 500 * (n+ 1), 1:]
```